# Incrementing int in Java within a loop

Tags: java, increment

I've searched all over in the last couple hours and I just can't get a simple counter going in Java! I tried AtomicInteger and it's getAndIncrement() method but that didn't work.

Basically I have a for loop, and within that an if statement, I want an int to be incremented by 1 everytime in the for loop the if statement equates to true. And then after the for loop, return the int.

The int doesn't increment.

Help!

Edit - It's on Eclipse for Android:

```
public int markTest(Map<Long, String> selectedAnswers,
            Map<Long, String> correctAnswers) {
        int mark = 0;
        for (long i = 1; i <= selectedAnswers.size(); i++) {

            String userSelection = selectedAnswers.get(i).toString();
            if (userSelection == correctAnswers.get(i))
                mark++;
        }

        return mark;
    }
```

Comment: `intValue++`?  I think your question might be missing some context

Comment: If you post what you have so far, it would be easier for someone to help you

Comment: Sorry, i've edited the question

Comment: I'll change that, however the if is definitely equating to true for the moment as I used Log.i - but the mark++ isn't doing its job

Comment: Because that's not how you compare strings, so `mark` is never incremented. Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: @OmairVaiyani I know you mean that you're sure both the values are same but trust us when we say `==` would still fail you there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to check string equality is to use `String.equals()` instead of equality `==` operator.

```
if (userSelection.equals(correctAnswers.get(i))) {
```

Since, your `if` condition is failing all the time *mark* is not getting incremented. Also, there's no need for `toString()` since *selectedAnswers* is already of type `Map<Long, String>`

```
String userSelection = selectedAnswers.get(i);
```

***References:***
[Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)
[How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

after the if statement write count++ example and don't forget to initialize the count outside the loop count=0 or what ever number you want to start with.

if(condition)
count++;

return count;